# Context Unresolved Reference

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm setting up my **RecyclerView's adapter,** and i need to use Activity Context to be filled in my *viewmodel* variable, and later i will using it to do move intent. Why i got **Unresolved Reference** even i put my context inside the class?

I've tried casting to FragmentActivity since the `of()` method asks for `FragmentActivity`, but still the same.

```java
class TodoAdapter constructor(x:ArrayList<Notes>, c: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.Handler>() {
    private var lists:ArrayList<Notes> = x
    private var context:Context = c
    private lateinit var viewmodel:TodoViewModel

    class Handler(private val itemBinding:NotesListBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {
        fun bind(note:Notes){
            itemBinding.dataclass = note
            itemBinding.viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(context).get(TodoViewModel::class.java)
            itemBinding.notesCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(note.color)
        }
    }
```

I expect that context will be well referenced since it's on the same class. But it returns error like:

```
e: /media/cua/Projectah/Android Studio/TODOLisT/app/src/main/java/com/cua/todolist/adapter/recyclerviewadapter/TodoAdapter.kt: (24, 59): Unresolved reference: context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `context` variable is unresolved, because `Handler` doesn't have a reference to `TodoAdapter`. To achieve this you'd have to declare it as `inner class Handler`. Though you should not do it!

Instead provide the `viewmodel` with `bind`:

```
fun bind(note: Notes, viewmodel: TodoViewModel) {
    itemBinding.dataclass = note
    itemBinding.viewmodel = viewmodel
    itemBinding.notesCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(note.color)
}
```

Also consider setting the card background color within the data binding as well.